# There's a way to verify apple certificates?

Tags: ios, objective-c, certificate

A big question: there's a way to verify all the chain of apple certificates when developing an app for ios?

I have a problem with push notification: i did all that must be done, all seems to go well (and in development all went perfectly) but now that the app is on the app store the notifications can not arrive. I tried a lot of solutions and no luck, so i'm thinking is a certificate problem... but how i can check what i've generated is correct or at the least check why the apple server does not send the notification when it receive my call?

Comment: I had a similar issue, albeit when moving from one development server to another. I went through the certification process again, which obviously isn't an option if your app is already live. You could perhaps try generating new server certificates based on the distribution profile on your app?

Comment: What drives me mad, is that the server never changed. After publication, i've only generated the certificate for distribution, overwrited the development certificate with the distribution one, changed the apple server on the php script and that's all. I've tried to do all from the beginning and nothing... What do you mean by generating new serve certificates? The one generated from the ssl distribution one by apple?